# Why does my angular/express nodemailer not include the from portion of email?

Tags: angularjs, email, express, nodemailer

I'm testing nodemailer with Angular/Express and the emails it sends have the same from/to email, my own.  I collect the sender's email address in req.body.email but it is not sent as such.  My Express Code:

```
var ContactUs = require('./contactUs.model');
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

// Creates a new contactUs in the DB.
exports.create = function(req, res) {
  console.log("export controller hit")

  console.log(req.body.email);

  var message = {

    // sender info
    from: '"Contact Us from" <req.body.email>',

    // Comma separated list of recipients
    to: '"Receiver Name" <myemail>',

    // Subject of the message
    subject:  req.body.email, // this is supposed to be req.body.name,
    // but I changed it because it's not sending the from email.

    text: req.body.comments

  };

  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
      user: 'myemail',
      pass: 'mypass'
    }
  });

  transporter.sendMail(message, function(error, info) {
    if (error) {
      console.log('Error occurred');
      console.log(error.message);
      res.end("error");
      return;
    }
    console.log('Message sent successfully!');
    console.log('Server responded with "%s"', info.res);
    res.end("sent");
  })
}
```

Comment: I think nodemailer is a bit buggy.  I encourage anyone visiting this post to go straight to mailgun. I worked well like it's supposed to; I spent far to long on nodemailer and could never get it to work right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use req.body.email like given format, it should

> **from: "Contact Us from <"+req.body.email+">"**

Comment: Thanks. I tried from: "Contact Us from <"+req.body.email+">" AND 
from: "Contact Us from "+req.body.email+""         Either way, it did not work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I used this format in one project, it is working for me.
**from: "no-reply<"+Config.senderEmail+">",**
Can you please share error.